# Prevent anchor tag reloading page on @click in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the following code in my vue file. The issue I am facing here is that page reloads when I click on here. I have added `event.preventDefault()` but couldn't resolve the issue. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
<template>
  <p>Please click <a @click="stopProcess">here</a></p>
</template>

<script>  
  export default {
    methods: {
      stopProcess(){
        event.preventDefault()
        var page = "../../../pages/page.pdf"
        window.open(page);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using window.open?

Comment: @LeonardoBezerra because I want to open the page in the new tab on click

Comment: window.open will only work with absolute links, using https. "https://yourdomain.com/pages/page.pdf"

Comment: Yes like @LeonardoBezerra it works only with http protocol and you should also add `'blank'` as second parameter to open that in new tab

Comment: What is your actual intention here? Downloading the pdf?

Comment: @SMAKSS open the file on new tab and prevent reloading of current page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code I would try this, but if it was me, I would use the router.

```html
<template>
  <p>Please click <a @click="stopProcess">here</a></p>
</template>

<script>  
  export default {
    methods: {
      stopProcess(){
        var page = window.location.origin + "/pages/page.pdf"
        window.open(page);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: this works with my app, It won't work if you have router installed

Comment: Yes i have routers installed.

Comment: How do u recommend using it with router?

Comment: You might want to checkout this instead https://www.pdftron.com/blog/webviewer/how-to-build-a-pdf-viewer-with-vuejs/

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `prevent` modifier to prevent the default behavior as follows  :

```
  <p>Please click <a @click.prevent="stopProcess">here</a></p>
```

or like you did but you missed the `event` as method parameter :

```
    stopProcess(event){
        event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: this maybe true but it's not the reason for the reload

Comment: @LeonardoBezerra why ?

Comment: @user12763413 did you try out `<a href="../../../pages/page.pdf" target="_blank">here</a>`

Comment: its reloads with pdf file or with old content?

Comment: the pdf file opens in next page but the page from where I clicked is reloaded

Comment: could you provide a codesandbox sample in order to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

So first of you need to know `@click` does not act like the native click event so `event.preventDefault()` may not work as expected to make this work, you need to make your native click event with using `@click.native`. Then you need to pass the `event` itself to your handler method *(The best way to handling the events in vue.js is to use [built-in event handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html), so you may get rid of `event.preventDefault()` and directly use `@click.prevent` instead)*.

But all of these alone won't solve your issue because by default if the requested route is in the same domain the current page will follow it after [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) happens so you need to pass the second value to it, to make sure the new path is not the same as the current one *(the preferred value for it is `_blank`)*. You also always may need to indicate a `href` for your `<a>`.

```html
<template>
  <p>Please click <a href="#" @click.native="stopProcess">here</a></p>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      stopProcess(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        var page = "../../../pages/page.pdf"
        window.open(page, '_blank');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

---

You can also make this much easier without any of this complicated stuff by setting the [`<a>`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjdstPuiPHqAhVO6qQKHZcMBrsQFjAMegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTML%2FElement%2Fa&usg=AOvVaw1u-N9ZBosH8L7bI7PKi0da) target to `_blank`.

```html
<template>
  <p>Please click <a href="../../../pages/page.pdf" target="_blank">here</a></p>
</template>
```

---

If you are using `vue-router` this could be something like this instead of above ones:

```html
<template>
  <p>Please click  <router-link to="../../../pages/page.pdf" target="_blank">Home</router-link></p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `href="javascript:void(0)"` inside your anchor tag definition, then the page will not reload.

This is because the void operator returns undefined, a result the browser doesn't act on. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) for more info on the void operator.

E.g: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" @click="stopProcess">here</a>`

Answer (score 0):

`@click.prevent` is the correct method, but the page will still be reloaded.

Since the `stopProcess()` will throw an exception because the `event` is not defined, the `prevent` modifier will not work.

Please remove the `event.preventDefault()` and add the `prevent` modifier and you will see it's working.

Comment: "A" tag doesn't cause the page to reload, so prevent will ONLY prevent the page from scrolling to the top of the page.